# Band Issues in Quickbird Satellite data

Tags: remote-sensing, raster-conversion, resolution, band, maxar-digitalglobe

I procure data from DigitalGlobe (Quickbird Satellite data) for different periods hence data having some different band combination. I have attached an example image to show the problem.

I am looking for your guidance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Red and Blue Bands appear switched in the March Image, as a big blue roof appears red, and red roofs appear blue.
To change it, go to Layer Properties -> Symbology -> the click the drop down menu for Red Band_1 and select Band_3, do the reverse for Blue. That should work.
[image]